# 空きドメインを調べるコマンド

Tags: linux

ドメインを取得する際に毎回レジストラのウェブサイトへ行って検索して確認するのがめんどくさいと感じています。
linuxのコマンドで調べる方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: whois コマンドではどうでしょう？

Answer (score 10):

`$ whois example.com`

で調べられます。

---

whois コマンドが入ってなければ CentOS なら

`$ sudo yum install jwhois`

Ubuntu なら

`$ sudo apt-get install whois`

でいけます。