# ドメインが取得できるか調べるコマンドはありますか？

Tags: linux, shellscript

`example.com`
`example.net`
`example.xyz`

などといった任意のドメインが取得できるか調べるコマンドはありますか？

> **同じ内容の質問がすでに存在していました**
>
> [空きドメインを調べるコマンド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6009/%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%8D%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89#comment4801_6009)
>
> > **Q**:ドメインを取得する際に毎回レジストラのウェブサイトへ行って検索して確認するのがめんどくさいと感じています。
> >     linuxのコマンドで調べる方法はないでしょうか。
> >
> > **A**:`whois example.com`
> >     で調べられます。

Comment: ドメインが取得できるかを調べるコマンドはないと思います。`whois example.com`で存在するドメインの情報を得ることはできます。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi さんありがとうございます。さすが偉大なPythonista ですね！

Comment: 僕が持っているドメイン（.comなどではない、変わったtop levelドメインです)は引けないので、100%ではないですよ。もちろんオプションを駆使してwhoisサーバーを直に指定すれば引けるのでしょうけど。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi わかりました。ドメインとは集約的に管理されているわけではなく、分散して管理しているため、whois コマンドでも検索ができない可能性があるんですね。はじめてしりました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unix系のOSであれば大抵whoisコマンドがあり、登録されているドメインに関する情報を調べることが出来ます。新規に取得されたドメインの情報がwhoisに反映されるまでは数十分～1日程度ですので、whoisで情報が出てこないドメインはおおむね取得されていないと判断できます。

```
% whois ieee.org
Domain Name: IEEE.ORG
Domain ID: D3043938-LROR
WHOIS Server:
Referral URL: http://www.networksolutions.com
Updated Date: 2013-05-01T14:59:11Z
Creation Date: 1989-12-01T05:00:00Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2016-11-30T05:00:00Z
Sponsoring Registrar: Network Solutions, LLC
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 2
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registrant ID: 20002737-NSI
Registrant Name: Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers, Inc.
(以下略)
```

Answer (score 0):

ドメインが空いている

`$ whois exist.com | grep -q "No match for" && echo 'Unavailable' || echo 'Available'`

**`Available`**

---

ドメインが取得済み

`$ whois domain-is-exist.com | grep -q "No match for" && echo 'Unavailable' || echo 'Available'`

**`Unavailable`**

Comment: `No match for` で検索しているので、`whois ... | grep -q 'No match for' && echo 'Available' || echo 'Unavailable'` となるのではないでしょうか(`Available` と `Unavailable` が逆)。

Comment: ドメインが見つからなかった時の応答はWHOISサーバによってNo match for .... だったり... no matchだったり No match!!だったりと様々なパターンがあります。No match forのあるなしでは判断出来ません。